# Foreign Key in SQL pivot table - database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I am using DBDesigner 4 for designing my database relations.

I have a `users` table and a `recipes` table. One user can **own** many recipes but one recipe cannot be owned by many users. This relationship is shown by the `user_recipes` relation in the picture. (A one-to-many relationship from `users` to `recipes`). [image]

However, recipes can be liked by users. Many users can like many recipes. This is a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `recipes` and the pivot table for this is `users_like_recipes`.

But when I create this pivot table, I only need the `users_id` and `recipes_id` column. The `recipes_users_id` column is getting added on its own and I am not able to remove it. It says the third column has come from another Relation which is defined in the model. I guess its the `user_recipes` relation.

When I remove the `user_recipes` relation, I get the pivot table like I want to.
[image]

But I need the `user_recipes` relation too!

Please. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest that you stop using the design tool and type your own create table queries.

Comment: A lot more tables are about to come and I need a software for maintaining the visual relationships. Do you know of any other database design tool?

Comment: Old question, but you could try [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).  But I prefer to build the database and the diagram separately, because I don't like a program deciding how to build my database based on lines I draw.  I use [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) to manage my db and Workbench when I need to draft a diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing user_id as a primary key from from the recipes table. Currently the combination if id and user_id provides identification for your recipes table. In this situation multiple user_id's can create the same recipe id because the combination has to be unique. user_id can just be a normal column in your table. If you REALLY want to, you can make an alternate key on (id, user_id) but you do not need it because the id is unique.

Comment: I see user id as a foreign key, not a primary key.

Comment: That would not make sense, you would not get recipes_user_id in the pivot table of it was not part of the primary key. If you make a foreign key relationship, you always get the entire primary key and nothing else.

Comment: "I see", in my previous comment refers to the content of the question, not my vision of how the tables should be designed.

Comment: I cannot make the `users_id` a normal column because when I add the `user_recipes` relation, the `users_id` comes automatically as a foreign key.

I guess this mechanism is enforced just to ensure data integrity and there is anyway no harm in keeping another extra column..?

Comment: @DanBracuk the key symbol before the column names indicate they are primary keys. But used as a foreign key

Comment: @Simon :O yes! How did you get that?

Comment: @AninditKarmakar I pushed [this button](http://i.imgur.com/NmZ4Kqu.png) then the users table and then the recipes table.

Comment: @Simon Thank you so much!

Now, what was the difference? What is the difference between an Identifying and a Non-Identifying relation? I'll Google it but if you could tell me in short?

Comment: primary keys are identifying. So if you  make an Identifying Relationship, you add the foreign key as a part of the primary key. In a Non-Identifying Relationship you add it only as a foreign key. Fun fact: your pivot table has two Identifying Relationships, one to your user table and one to your recipes table.